# Вставить Данные в таблицу через INSERT из другой таблицы и при этом добавить свои значения в строку

Tags: база-данных, sqlite

Решение нагуглить не смог. Нужно создать запись и подтянуть из другой таблицы 3 значения, а другие 2 вписать самому. Как я могу это сделать ? Нужно как-то дописать Values ?
В прикрепленном ниже запросе хочу сделать так, чтобы idproductd, productname и price, подтягивались из другой таблицы, а idclient и status вводились путем переменных в программе.
Использовать два запросы по типу Insert , а потом Update, по идее, не вариант.

```
INSERT INTO orders (idclient, idproductd, productname, price, status) 
SELECT id, productname, price FROM dogs WHERE id = {переменная}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: `SELECT id, productname, price, 'Переменная1', 'Переменная2' FROM ` - Вам никто не запрещает в селекте указывать значения. Единственное, соблюдайте правильную последовательность

Comment: Не могу найти, где именно кнопка ответить тут, но решение SwaD очень помогло, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В SELECT можно подставлять константы значений и это так же будет работать

```
INSERT INTO orders(idclient, idproductd, productname, price, status) 
SELECT id, 'Переменная 1', productname, price, 'Переменная 2' FROM dogs 
WHERE id ={переменная}
```

Единственное, при таком подходе надо соблюдать правильную последовательность перечисленных полей в INSERT и в SELECT